# Git, сделал локальные изменения на master, хочу запушить на новую ветку в удаленном репозитории

Tags: git, git-commit, git-push, git-branch

Сейчас у меня есть не зафиксированные изменения в локальном репе, ветка стоит master.
Как запушить изменения на новую ветку в удаленном репе.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос то:

```
git checkout -b название_ветки // создаем ветку и переключаемся на нее
git commit -am "..." //Добавляем и комитим изменения
git remote -v // смотрим удаленные репозитории скорее всего (origin)
git push origin // отправили изменения + новую ветку
```

В дальнейшем, когда будете делать новые изменения, то создавайте новую ветку или переключайтесь на существующую для проведения работ.

```
//А когда работы хотите зафиксировать в удаленном репо то:
git push origin <нужная_ветка>
```

Comment: первую и вторую команды надо местами поменять: похоже, что вопрос как раз про это.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin точно.. Я просто думал, что ветка уже есть и на нее не переключиться пока не закомитишь изменения. Поправил

Comment: лучше `git push --set-upstream origin <нужная_ветка>`